# Downloading Multiple Files in background Using NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, ios7, background-process, nsurlsession

I have implemented a catalog app(iOS7) which contains a set of videos showcasing the products.In my app i have provided a feature that allows user to download all the videos by enabling it.It starts the download process when app goes in background.The video sizes are typically 15-20 MB each and consists around 100 videos.It already has a feature to download while app is in foreground.Right now the downloads are happening in background using NSURLSession.I need to know whether there is any issue with this approach?

Comment: I hope there is no issue. Because it is provided by apple it self in ios7. So that's why you can use it without any headache.

Comment: Ok i thought it would be good to ask if anybody already have an app with background downloading functionality in Appstore.